# 得數條別錄 - what does it mean exactly?

Tags: translation, classical-chinese

There is this passage from a Korean Confucian Yun Hyu, where he discusses relation between 理 and 動:  理動之說，非某之說，朱夫子嘗屢言之矣。今得數條別錄以上，乞以此更入思量，如何。

I am at loss with "今得數條別錄以上" this part. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it would be:

now (今) [i] got (得) several (數) tidbits (條), separately (別) recorded (錄)) for (以) submitting (上 —> 呈上)

“條” referred to paragraphs ( groups of several sentences, less than an article)

have fun :)

btw: your reading material is quite interesting, may i know the name of your book?

Comment: The book is 被誤讀的儒學史. Very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading the whole text, I have to make some presumptions.

I presume:

- 理 = 理論 (theory)
- 動 = 行動 (action)
- 說 = 說法/論據 (argument)

> 理動之說，非某之說，朱夫子嘗屢言之矣。今得數條別錄以上，乞以此更入思量，如何。

> The arguments between theory and action is not my arguments, Master Zhu has mentioned them repeatedly. Now I have a few of them listed separately above, please take them into consideration, how about that?

今 - now

得 - (I've) got

數條 - (論據) - a few (arguments)

別錄 - separately listed

以上 - above

or

以 - to

上 - submit

*條 is a classifier for 論據*